# Cannot determine a dialect for MySQL using dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnectionFactory@70d2e40b. Please provide a Dialect

Tags: spring-webflux, r2dbc

When compiling I receive an error:

> org.springframework.data.r2dbc.dialect.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for MySQL using dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnectionFactory@70d2e40b. Please provide a Dialect.

Interestingly, the application seems to work fine when I launch it through IntelliJ. It only fails, when I launch it from a .jar file.

I've considered that application.properties might affect it, but it seems that during compilation only the configuration class is referenced.

Here is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class R2DBCconfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

@Override
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
   return MySqlConnectionFactory.from(MySqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
           .host("localhost")
           .port(3306)
                   .username("root")
                   .password("password")
                   .database("database")
           .build());
} }
```

Does anyone have any pointers regarding this?